# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) for some of the images

Tags: php, html, wampserver

I am having a weird variation of the
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

I am trying to get images from a server and populate divs as follows:

```
<?php for( $i = 0 ; $i<sizeof($files); $i++){
    $courseLoc = ('course/' . $CourseID . '/' . $files[$i]); ?> 

    <div id="<?php echo $files[$i];?>" class="selectable" style="display: inline-block;">

       <?php if(strpos($files[$i], 'jpg') !== false || strpos($files[$i], 'png') !== false || strpos($files[$i], 'jpeg') !== false){ ?>
           <img src="<?php echo('course/' . $CourseID . '/' . $files[$i]) ;?>" alt="<?php $files[$i];?>" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
       <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

The data is being obtained properly however only one image is being displayed while the other 3 are giving the above error. Most of the solutions I found handled the whole thing giving error 403 or modifying the .htaccess file which does not even exist apparently on my version of wampserver. Any suggestions? The paths and existence of the files have been verified and are proper.

Edit:
Content of `$files` is `Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => Dialect (1).png [3] => Dialect.png [4] => LinReg.png [5] => WhatsApp Image 2017-11-22 at 10.21.56 PM.jpeg )`

Comment: It might be very helpful to see the contents of your `$file` array! If you actually want us to help you.

Comment: I assume you checked that the folder `course/$CourseId/` exists and has all thes files in it

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hello, i edited the content of the `$file` array into the question. Also yes I am sure that the directory exists and all files are inside. The `dialects(1).png` image is the only one that appears and doesn't give this error

Comment: Also, please note that I remove the first 2 elements `.` and `..` if you want the code I would happily provide

Comment: Did you check which users own the files using "ls -lha ./*" ?

Comment: @DannyZB I didn't but I am using the admin account and I already tried using chmod to give all users all access to the content.